# blender error as soon open project

Tags: error

So last night I added an image texture to my object. I set the resolution to 10000 x 10000 because it's a really big object that needs high resolution, and my blender became very laggy. So I saved and planned to continue the next morning, thinking the lag will be gone, but when I woke up and opened up my project, blender closed by itself with no error message or any pop up error message. I tried to delete my image texture (I think that's the problem and why my project isn't functioning) but it still doesn't work. Any helpful suggestions?

Comment: Start blender from command line with `--debug-all --factory-startup` flags and check console output for errors.

Comment: I do as what you said, i can open up my project now, thanks.